# MERN stack Ec2 deployed website does not log in

Tags: reactjs, typescript, amazon-ec2, mern

Seeking some help, trying to deploy a mern stack application on aws using ec2 instances. Everythings going well I can register new users and I can log in, problem is it doesn't stay logged in, the user instantly becomes undefined. Has anyone ran into this problem before? Think it might have something to do with the cookies. As Postman works good, its able to log in and then retrieve user.

Featured is the middleware code using Passport.

```
const LocalStrategy = passportLocal.Strategy;
mongoose.connect(...);
// Middleware
const app = express();
app.use(express.json());
//before deployment
//app.use(cors({origin:"http://localhost:3000",credentials:true}))

app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(cors({origin:"http://ec2-18-191-200-43.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com:3000",credentials:true}))
app.use(
    session({
        secret:"secretcode",
        resave:true,
        saveUninitialized:true,
        cookie:{
          sameSite:false
        }
    })
);
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

//Passport 
passport.use(new LocalStrategy((username:string, password:string, done) => {
    User.findOne({ username: username }, (err:any, user: DatabaseUserInterface) => {
      if (err) throw err;
      if (!user) {
        console.log("not user");
        return done(null, false);
      }
      bcrypt.compare(password, user.password, (err, result:boolean) => {
        if (err) throw err;
        if (result === true) {
          console.log("good should be logged in");
          return done(null, user);
        } else {
            //unuathorised
          console.log("unathorised");
          return done(null, false);
        }
      });
    });
  })
  );
  
  passport.serializeUser((user: DatabaseUserInterface, cb) => {
    cb(null, user._id);
  });
  
  passport.deserializeUser((id: string, cb) => {
    User.findOne({ _id: id }, (err: any, user: DatabaseUserInterface) => {
      const userInformation :UserInterface = {
        username: user.username,
        isAdmin: user.isAdmin,
        id: user._id,
        wins:user.wins,
        losses:user.losses
      };
      cb(err, userInformation);
    });
  });
//log in 
app.post("/login", passport.authenticate("local"), (req, res) => {
    res.send("success");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Follow up: Im an aws noob, and thought you had to run 2 different clusters with 2 different instances to run 2 tasks. You in fact only need 1 cluster with 1 instance that can run as many tasks as you want. This way cookies can actually be transferred between the ports used by the different tasks i.e. front and backend.